# Android Spinner not redawn after calling setSelection()

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a **Spinner** in my app that is populated from an array and whose width is `wrap_content`.

The elements are:

```
String[] items = {
    "Select...",
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
}
```

The UI also has a **CLEAR** button which calls:

```
spinner.setSelection(0, true); // Using false doesn't help.
```

When I start the app, the currently selected item is correctly shown as ***Select...***.

If I then select "2" item, the spinner correctly shows ***2***.

But if I then click the clear button, the spinner only shows a truncated ***Sel***.

After the call to `setSelection()`, it seems like the Spinner has failed to redraw itself. In this case, it's a problem because the newly selected string is longer than the previous one - hence the truncation on the UI.

To solve, after `setSelection()`, I've tried adding

```
spinner.invalidate();
```

then

```
spinner.post(() -> { // postDelayed() makes no difference either.
    spinner.invalidate();
});
```

but neither solve the problem.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Here's the layout for my spinners:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerDobDay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:hint="@string/select_day" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerDobMonth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/spinnerDobDay"
    android:hint="@string/select_month" />
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerDobYear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/spinnerDobMonth"
    android:hint="@string/select_year" />
```

Comment: can you please share your spinner layout .. I couldn't reproduce the isse

Comment: @Zain Thanks, I've added it now.

Comment: Please try to add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"` to the `spinner`, not totally sure if that would solve it

Comment: Also try to use a custom adapter if you're using the default `ArrayAdapter`; and use custom open/closed spinner item layouts instead of the built-in ones.